# Como reduzir o consumo de CPU de aplicação JSF

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, cache, profiling

De um tempo para cá, minha aplicação começou a ter um consumo de CPU muito grande. Instalei o JProfiler, e pelo que entendi dele, há um problema com o c3p0 do hibernate.
Estou usando hibernate 4.3, jsf2.2.10 + primefaces 5.2, uso ehcache também.

Segue abaixo alguns resultados que printei.

[image: imagem consumo mchange]

[image: Threads .data]

[image: thread tree]

[image: hibernate config]

Comment: Marlucio, qual é o banco de dados da app? Veja se não está ocorrendo locks no banco de dados. Fora isso, o que mudou na vida da aplicação (uso ou atualização) que coincide com o aumento do consumo de CPU?

Comment: Banco MySQL 5.6.  Não mudou muita coisa. O que me estranha que mesmo sem ninguém usar, tipo horários durante a madrugada. Ou sem sessão estão gerando tal consumo.

Answer (score 1):

Vendo os gráficos apresentados, creio que você interpretou incorretamente o problema.

Não vi consumo de CPU como sendo o problema, até porque esta informação não é mostrada. A quantidade de % que está vendo não é CPU, mas é tempo gasto executando aquele método. A causa pode ser várias coisas (inclusive CPU).

No seu caso em específico, **o C3P0 parece estar demorando para conseguir uma conexão** com o banco de dados. O pool de conexões serve para agilizar isto, pois o C3P0 mantém algumas conexões sempre abertas e, quando a aplicação pede uma conexão, ela já tem uma pronta para usar.

Contudo, se esta etapa está demorando, **é possível que o pool atual esteja muito pequeno** (na sua configuração atual, está como 5) e ele esteja precisando abrir novas conexões com o banco de dados. Abrir uma conexão nova com o banco de dados é algo mais pesado, o que explicaria seu problema.

Outra explicação é você **ter alcançado o número máximo de conexões**, que atualmente você configurou como 20. Quando isto ocorre, o sistema precisa aguardar para utilizar uma conexão aberta, o que explicaria também a demora.

Os dois casos acima podem ser monitorados no servidor ou diretamente no banco de dados, acompanhando a quantidade de conexões abertas.

Para melhorar, você pode aumentar o pool mínimo ou máximo de conexões, dependendo do seu problema. Tente um número maior que 5 para o mínimo, por exemplo. O número exato eu não posso dizer qual pode ser, pois depende muito da sua aplicação e do servidor.

Se notar que este problema é mais grave em horários específicos (como na madrugada) **verifique também se não existe nenhuma rotina pesada sendo rodada no banco de dados** durante o horário. Talvez isto possa afetar o tempo de abertura de uma nova conexão.

Comment: poxa, não tinha recebido notificação de sua resposta.É porque não mostrei o gerenciador de tarefas. Está sempre 99% em uso. Obrigado, vou testar aqui amigo.

Comment: Cara não resolveu. Mudei os números e continua na mesma.